# Javascript - Running a pushState script on pageload

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run the following script on pageload so that it pushes the querystring value into the page onpageload not sure how to combine the two arguments.

```
window.history.pushState('{ }','','?semester=March');
return false;

window.onload = window.history.pushState('{ }','','?semester=March');
return false;
```

Comment: That is not a question, only a description of what you'd like to do. In what way is it failing? Are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: The 1st line of code is working fine when attached to a button, but how can i have it execute automatically when the page loads instead of a button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently assigning the result of executing the `pushState()` function (which is `undefined`) to `window.onload`. But you have to assign a callback function to it that will be triggered when the `onload` event fires.

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.history.pushState('{ }','','?semester=March');
}
```

Comment: Should be mentioned to just replace the URL, use `history.replaceState('{ }','', '?semester=March')` instead, as to not create a history entry.